# Spring Security SAML extension ADFS

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml, adfs3.0

I've been working whit the SAML extension to connect to an ADFS server. I've hacked the sample application to use my ADFS server and everything went well, but I would like to know if there is a way to connect to an IDP without using the loging page of the IDP. I mean if there is a way to do this process in background for the end-user. I am thinking about doing a query to ADFS or something like to get the users and do authentication from the SP login page, avoiding the need for the user to authenticate in the IDP login page.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of federated authentication is to delegate it to a centralized server in such a way that the relaying parties/service providers do not have access to user's credentials. Enabling authentication directly in your application would violate this principle and for this reason is not supported by neither Spring SAML nor ADFS.

If you want to authenticate your users directly, use authentication directly against Active Directory instead of ADFS. This will fully support your use-case.